# Navbar not clickable, bugged bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with my navbar that is bugged only when i use "$(document).ready(function(){".
The problem is that the toggle button on the navbar can't be clicked..
If i get out the "$(document).ready(function(){" the toggle button is working properly...

I found a lot of subjects talking about this problem, but no one solution was working for me :(

The page that has the problem :

```
<?php
require_once("../../include/js/ShowNotif.php");
$title_page = "Liste des namespaces - Name";
require_once("../../include/head.php");
?>

  <!-- Main content -->
  <div class="main-content" id="panel">
..
..
<div id="results"></div>
</div>
<?php
  require_once("../../include/js/js.php");
?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
              $.ajax({
                url : "../../ajax/getnamespacesbdd.php",
                type : 'GET',
                success : function(data, statut){
                  $('#results').html(data);
                },
                error : function(resultat, statut, erreur){
                  ShowMessageNotification('error', 'Aïe ! C\'est une erreur de GET ! L\'API est down ?', 4000, 'top-end');
                }
              });
            })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the head.php

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700">
  <!-- Icons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/vendor/nucleo/css/nucleo.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" type="text/css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/vendor/datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/vendor/datatables.net-buttons-bs4/css/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/vendor/datatables.net-select-bs4/css/select.bootstrap4.min.css">
  <!-- Page plugins -->
  <!-- Argon CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/css/argon.css?v=1.2.0" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <script src="../../assets/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
...
...
```

There is no error is the dev tool.
Thanks !

Comment: `#results` is not in your HTML so the AJAX cannot insert the result.

Comment: Yes it is in the ".. .. " ;) the data is displayed, no problem on it